# ASP.Net Connection String Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.Net and I'm going through this database tutorial:

https://www.guru99.com/insert-update-delete-asp-net.html

I created a new database "test" on Microsoft SQL Server Management Tool.

[image]

However, my connectionString in Visual Studio returns a 'login failed for user testerguy6' when I run it.

[image]

Does anyone see the issue here?

Comment: Did you create a login, or only a database user?

Comment: Open the exception in your debugger and see what the inner exception and message read. (click on the *View Details* hyper-link in that popup)

Comment: Side note: A tutorial that doesn't teach you how to properly use and dispose a connection should not be taken seriously

Comment: Also try specifying only the Server/Instance name of your SQL server in your connection string after you made sure that the user exists and is able to login.

Comment: See the login details for the user, it seems the login is not created.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure you have correct permission set against the database.

In MSSQL Server Management Studio go to:

**Security** > **Logins** > on the db user (testerguy6) **right click** > **Properties** > in the new window click **User Mapping** (on the left hand side) and tick:

- db owner
- db datareader
- db datawriter